# Mirror content based on URL slug

Tags: permalinks, url-rewriting, the-content

I have a training site that manages the same content across several branded versions.

examples:

- .com/product-name-a
- .com/re-brand1/product-name-a
- .com/re-brand2/product-name-a

Where all 3 are the same content.

In a perfect world, the "product-name-a" would only exist once, and if updated, shows globally.

I feel like this is in the re-write API relm, but unsure since I don't actually want to re-direct, just display the requested page in the requested URL.

Comment: Basically this is a support / training site with white labeled content, but the content needs to be coming from the same source, and stay current. So a page copy wont work.